# Как сделать курсор перед печатающиймся текстом?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, что-бы когда текст набирался перед ним был курсор? и когда текст закончился курсор пропал? Спасибо

```js
function writeTextByJS(id, text, speed) {

    const ele = document.querySelector('.main-home__subtitle');
    const txt = text.join("").split("");

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        if (!txt[0]) {

            return clearInterval(interval);
        };

        ele.innerHTML += txt.shift();
    }, speed != undefined ? speed : 80); //скорость

    return false;
};

writeTextByJS(
    ".main-home__subtitle", //селектор
    [
        "TeXT TeXT TeXT \n",
        "TeXT TeXT TeXT TeXT \n"
    ]
);
```

```css
.main-home__subtitle{
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-home__subtitle"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно по классу добавлять для элемента псевдо-элемент `::after`, который будет выполнять роль каретки.

```js
function writeTextByJS(id, text, speed) {

  const ele = document.querySelector('.main-home__subtitle');
  const txt = text.join("").split("");

  ele.classList.add("carriage"); // added

  var interval = setInterval(function() {

    if (!txt[0]) {

      ele.classList.remove("carriage"); // added
      return clearInterval(interval);
    };

    ele.innerHTML += txt.shift();
  }, speed != undefined ? speed : 80); //скорость

  return false;
};

writeTextByJS(
  ".main-home__subtitle", //селектор
  [
    "TeXT TeXT TeXT \n",
    "TeXT TeXT TeXT TeXT \n"
  ]
);
```

```css
.main-home__subtitle {
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Added */
.carriage::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #909090;
  height: 1em;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fading 700ms infinite;
}

@keyframes fading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-home__subtitle"></div>
```